# in string contains if-query

Tags: php, string

I am searching for a solution for fixing the below code

```
$tableString .= "
    <tr>
    <td>img</td>
    <td>"
    if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart'])){
        ."<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>"
        }
    if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Material'])){
        ."<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>"
```

I always get an error when this code runs, but I am unsure what is causing it.

Comment: Read the error. Fix the error.

Comment: You cannot use `if` construct within expression. Use ternary operator instead

Comment: What error do you get? What do you think it means? What did you try to do to solve it? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is totally messed up. You've got IF statements within concatenating stings. Rogue dots/periods within the IFs that mean absolutely nothing, missing semicolons etc.

See below:

```
$tableString .= "<tr><td>img</td><td>";
if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart'])){
    $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
}
if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Material'])){
    $tableString .= ."<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into this:

```
$tableString .= "
    <tr>
    <td>img</td>
    <td>";
if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart'])){
        $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
}
if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Material'])){
        $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
}
```

You cannot use a if statement inside an expression. So split your code in multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$tableString .= "
<tr>
<td>img</td>
<td>";

if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart'])){
    $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
    }
if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Material'])){
    $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
```

Comment: `+=` doesn't work for concatenating strings, use `.=`

Comment: Yup, already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
    $tableString .= "<tr>
    <td>img</td>
    <td>";
    if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart'])){
        $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
        }
    if (!empty($configArray[$configCounter]['Material'])){
        $tableString .= "<p> Glasart: ".$configArray[$configCounter]['Glasart']."</p>";
    }
```